# microsoft azure table authentication stringtosign error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am having a problem with `stringtosign` authentication for azure table pagination query.

This is the current `stringtosign` im using :

```
GET\n\n\nFri, 05 Sep 2014 03:57:11 GMT\n/mystorageaccount/mytablename\nNextPartitionKey:1!20!UmFjZSBNZW1iZXJfNA--\nNextRowKey:1!12!TmFtZV85ODE-
```

Is there anything wrong with this `stringtosign` authentication?
The rest of the Headers are exactly the same as Fiddle.

**Example**

```
GET /mytablename?NextPartitionKey=1%2120%21UmFjZSBNZW1iZXJfNA--&NextRowKey=1%2112%21TmFtZV85ODE- HTTP/1.1
Host: mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 05:49:19 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey mystorageaccount:GD2w4pqsllzIOixNF/AfFqLkZhYzLpjK67a8OI7j6Go=
Accept: application/atom+xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
```

I have read through both

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179428.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx

Hi Gaurav Mantri,

It still did not work. I'll paste the request, my stringtosign and the response below:

```
GET /mytablename?NextPartitionKey=1%2120%21UmFjZSBNZW1iZXJfNA--&NextRowKey=1%2112%21TmFtZV85ODE- HTTP/1.1
Host: mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 07:05:12 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey mystorageaccount:HSYfO1Baadqcd4bQO5Q6uN1hrr2aXtLcQbFPkWgIXuw=
Accept: application/atom+xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
```

String to sign:

```
GET\n\n\nFri, 05 Sep 2014 07:05:12 GMT\n/mystorageaccount/mytablename\nnextpartitionkey:1!20!UmFjZSBNZW1iZXJfNA--\nnextrowkey:1!12!TmFtZV85ODE-
```

Response:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><m:error xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\"><m:code>AuthenticationFailed</m:code><m:message xml:lang=\"en-US\">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:37272f11-0002-0014-5aa7-f7dd1c000000
Time:2014-09-05T07:05:09.5720897Z</m:message></m:error>
```

Comment: Are you using `SharedKey` or `SharedKeyLite` authentication scheme?

Comment: I'm currently using sharedkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an opportunity to actually write the code and try it out. Basically when creating CanonicalizedResource string for table resources, you need not include the query string parameters other than `comp` querystring parameter. Essentially this is what you would need to follow from the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179428.aspx):

> **2009-09-19 Shared Key Lite and Table Service Format**
>
> This format supports Shared Key and Shared Key Lite for all versions
>   of the Table service, and Shared Key Lite for the 2009-09-19 version
>   of the Blob and Queue services and 2014-02-14 of the File service.
>   This format is identical to that used with previous versions of the
>   storage services. Construct the CanonicalizedResource string in this
>   format as follows:
>
> 1. Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/), followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>      accessed.
> 2. Append the resource's encoded URI path. If the request URI addresses a component of the resource, append the appropriate query
>      string. The query string should include the question mark and the comp
>      parameter (for example, ?comp=metadata). No other parameters should be
>      included on the query string.

Once you do that, your code should run just fine. Here's the sample code I wrote:

```
    static void QueryTable()
    {
        var requestMethod = "GET";
        var storageServiceVersion = "2014-02-14";
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
        var canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", StorageAccount, TableName);
        var stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n{2}", requestMethod, date, canonicalizedResource);
        var authorizationHeader = GetAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign);
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(TableEndpoint);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", date);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

            var result = httpClient.GetAsync(TableName + "?NextPartitionKey=1!48!VXwzMzg0MDAzOWYzMjQ0ZDgxOWZjZmM5M2EyMzNkM2IxOA--&NextRowKey=1!0!");
            result.Wait();
        }
    }

    static string GetAuthorizationHeader(string canonicalizedString)
    {
        var signature = string.Empty;
        using (var hash = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageAccountKey)))
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(data));
        }

        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", StorageAccount, signature);
    }
```

<del>Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179428.aspx (2009-09-19 Shared Key Format Section, point #4), you would need to **convert all query parameters to lowercase**. So your canonicalized resource string should be:</del>

```
GET\n\n\nFri, 05 Sep 2014 03:57:11 GMT\n/mystorageaccount/mytablename\nnextpartitionkey:1!20!UmFjZSBNZW1iZXJfNA--\nnextrowkey:1!12!TmFtZV85ODE-
```

Give it a try. That should take care of the problem.

Comment: Why is there a space before `nextpartitionkey` in `stringtosign`?

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this out

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for the time taken to help me! I would vote up however I dont have enough reputation. But all in all thanks for your help! It works now