# Azure table service: authorize in REST API from Perl

Tags: azure, rest, perl

I'm trying to authorize in Azure Tables via REST API, from my Perl script. According to [MSDN documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) and basing on my knowledge of similar task (I've created a similar script for Blob service and it works well) I've developed a simple script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_base64);
use HTTP::Date;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;


my $account = 'myaccount';
my $key = 'Nf2b/ZSY+a...7ZT0Q==';
my $decoded_key = decode_base64( $key );

my $uri = "https://$account.table.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties";
my $method = 'GET';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new($method, $uri);

my $date = time2str();

    
my $canonicalized_resource = "/$account/\nrestype:service\ncomp:properties";

my $string_to_sign =
    "$method\n" .
    "\n" . # content-md5
    "\n" . # content-type
    "$date\n".
    $canonicalized_resource;
        

my $sig = hmac_sha256_base64($string_to_sign, $decoded_key );
$sig .= '=' x (4 - (length($sig) % 4));

$req->authorization("SharedKey $account:$sig");
$req->header('x-ms-version', '2019-02-02');
$req->header('x-ms-date', $date);
$req->date($date);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $resp = $ua->request($req);

unless($resp->is_success){
    die "Request failed: " . $resp->status_line . ". Signed string: " . $string_to_sign;
}
```

The task is pretty easy: check my code by getting [Table service properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-service-properties). Unfortunately it does not work! I'm getting:

> Request failed: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure, but according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) it seems `$string_to_sign` is missing some items (like Content-Encoding)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SharedKey` is incorrect. However, I'm not familiar with Perl. You could refer to the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25680076/13308381) with C#.

Plz check your [`CanonicalizedResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#shared-key-format-for-2009-09-19-and-later) string:

> 1. Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/), followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>    accessed.
> 2. Append the resource's encoded URI path, without any query parameters.
> 3. Retrieve all query parameters on the resource URI, including the comp parameter if it exists.
> 4. Convert all parameter names to lowercase.
> 5. **Sort the query parameters lexicographically by parameter name, in ascending order.**
> 6. URL-decode each query parameter name and value.
> 7. Include a new-line character (\n) before each name-value pair.
> 8. Append each query parameter name and value to the string in the following format, making sure to include the colon (:) between the
>    name and the value: `parameter-name:parameter-value`
> 9. If a query parameter has more than one value, sort all values lexicographically, then include them in a comma-separated list:
>    `parameter-name:parameter-value-1,parameter-value-2,parameter-value-n`

Comment: Thank you! Table service is a bit different from Blob, so CanonicalizedResource is different as well. I've got my script working when changed this: my $canonicalized_resource = "/$account/?comp=properties";. Looks different from Blob, but works. The C# example helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to know that. I find a [blog](http://programminghave.blogspot.com/2015/03/wrestling-azure-storage-rest-api-part-2.html) that shows the same example in **Canonicalized Resources**: `GET https://<account-name>.table.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties HTTP/1.1`

Here the canonicalized resource will be `/myaccount/?comp=properties`